# How can you enforce a subclass of an NSObject-based base class override a class-level variable?

Tags: swift, abstract-class, swift4, swift-protocols

Completely rewriting this question yet again to hopefully put the focus on the issue I'm trying to solve.

We have the following class that, due to an external framework outside of our control, requires us to implement `ObjCProtocolRequiringBla`, like so...

```
class FooBase : NSObject, ObjCProtocolRequiringBla {

    class var possibleValues:[String] {
        // Note: Use preconditionFailure, not fatalError for things like this.
        // At runtime, they both halt execution, but precondition(Failure)
        // only logs the message for debug builds. Additionally,
        // in debug builds it pauses in a debuggable state rather than crash.
        preconditionFailure("You must override possibleValues")
    }

    // This satisfies the objective-c protocol requirement
    final func getBla() -> Bla {
        let subclassSpecificValues = type(of:self).possibleValues
        return Bla(withValues:subclassSpecificValues)
    }
}

class FooA : FooBase
    override class var possibleValues:[String] {
        return [
            "Value A1",
            "Value A2",
            "Value A3"
        ]
    }
}

class FooB : FooBase
    override class var possibleValues:[String] {
        return [
            "Value B1",
            "Value B2",
            "Value B3",
            "Value B4"
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, `possibleValues` is used in the implementation of `getBla()`.  Additionally, it has to be common to all instances of that particular subclass, hence being a class variable and not an instance variable.  This is because in another place in the code, we have to retrieve all possible values across all subclasses, like so...

```
static func getAllPossibleValues:[String] {
    return [
        FooA.possibleValues,
        FooB.possibleValues
    ].flatMap { $0 }
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out how to do is make the compiler complain if a subclass of `FooBase` does not implement `possibleValues`.

In other words, how can we make this report a compile-time error:

```
class FooC : FooBase
    // Doesn't override class var possibleValues
}
```

Currently the only way I know of is the above, defining it in the base class with a `preconditionFailure` or similar, but that's a runtime check, not compile-time so it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm trying to figure out how to do is make the compiler complain if a subclass of FooBase does not implement `possibleValues`.

You can't. You can make something like `possibleValues` a protocol requirement and try to adopt that protocol, obviously, but if FooBase itself implements `possibleValues` you cannot get the *compiler* to complain if a subclass fails to override it. This is not a silly idea and there are probably computer languages that give you a way to do it, but Swift is not such a language. That's why the runtime solution is the best you can hope for, and that's the standard pattern, as you can see if you look at something like UIPopoverBackgroundView.

Comment: Yeah.  That's what I was afraid of.  If it wasn't for that Objective-C protocol, I could use protocol-oriented programming, defining the protocol, then implementing `getBla` in an extension, but you can't satisfy an Objective-C protocol in an extension.  This also could have been solved if Swift ever decides to adopt abstract classes, but that doesn't look like it will ever be the case either.  Ironically, this is the only limitation I've ever run across in Swift that hasn't allowed me to solve it the way I'd like... at compile time. Love this language!

Comment: The situation is well summarised by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49346872/341994

Comment: "but that doesn't look like it will ever be the case either" I wouldn't say that. Discussions of future Swift features are ongoing and open, and you are allowed to contribute. Jump in! As I say, your idea is hardly a silly one, and one can imagine something like a `@mustOverride` attribute that would solve the problem in one stroke.

Comment: Yeah, again, I'd normally use POP, and am a huge fan. The problem is POP fails here because of the Objective-C requirement so you can't implement the default behavior in an extension, which is the POP way. It has to be implemented in a base-class that inherits `NSObject`.

Comment: See for example https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0026-abstract-classes-and-methods.md — it is clear that something like what you want is in the hopper. But implementation is definitely not here yet.

Comment: Man, if they ever added that, I'd be ecstatic!  As I said, that's really the only limitation of this language that I've seen.  Everything else I've managed to 'Swift-ify' and in a lot of cases, much more elegantly than in those other languages.  This is just the one place that falls short for me.

Comment: The other solution could be--and this is without giving it much detailed thought--if you could mark a protocol extension as being able to fulfill an Objective-C's protocol requirements. The compiler would have to figure out if it's being applied on a NSObject already and if so, tack on that code (essentially moving it from the extension to that class), but for cases where the protocol is applied to something else (struct, Swift class, etc.) then I'm not sure how to solve that. @mustOverride (ala abstract classes) would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by replacing your FooBase class with a protocol that extends NSObjectProtocol. This will force any class implementing your protocol to having to be a subclass of NSObject and also implement the properties and methods you want.

```
protocol foo: NSObjectProtocol {
    var someProp: String {get set}

    func someFunc() -> Void
}
```

To have the protocol being used from Objective-C one can use the @objc annotation, this works at least for simple scenarios such as sending an selector, #selector(), as a parameter.

```
@objc protocol foo: NSObjectProtocol {
  var someProp: String {get set}

  func someFunc() -> Void
}
```

With that the following code worked fine

```
class fooClass: NSObject, foo {
  var someProp: String

  init(someProp: String) {
    self.someProp = someProp
  }

  func someFunc() {
    print("In someFunc with property: \(someProp)")
  }

  func timeIt() {
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0,  
    target: self, selector: #selector(someFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    print("timer created")
    timer.fire()
  }
}

func main() {
  let f = fooClass(someProp: "test")
  f.timeIt()
}

main()
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but does that mean when defining the subclasses, I now have to subclass NSObject *and* adhere to the protocol?  I'm ok with that if this works (I'll have to experiment).

Comment: I thought subclassing NSObject was a requirement. If it's not then just skip extending NSObjectProtocol.

Comment: It is, but it was handled by `FooBase`.  The subclasses simply inherited `FooBase` and thus got `NSObject` for free. You said to replace `FooBase`, meaning I now had to do that as well.  BTW, I just updated the question with more details.  The function in `FooBase` must be callable from Objective-C.  Can you write a protocol that supports Objective-C (like you've done here), then in an extension on it, implement a method callable from Objective-C? Is it as simple as tagging it with @objc?

Comment: Reworked the question with more details that are relevant.  LMK if that changes anything for your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure about the obj-c part but I did a quick test with a Timer that worked. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, perhaps? I didn't hammer out every last detail, but I think this covers a lot of your programming problem. If you'd like to discuss it further, let's start a chatroom rather than continuing to post endless comments here.

```
// Just to get it to compile
class Bla { init(withValues: [String]) {} }
protocol ObjCProtocolRequiringBla {}

class FooContainer : ObjCProtocolRequiringBla {
    fileprivate var fooCore: FooProtocol

    fileprivate init(_ fooCore: FooProtocol) { self.fooCore = fooCore }

    // This satisfies the objective-c protocol requirement
    final func getBla() -> Bla { return fooCore.getBla() }
}

protocol FooProtocol {
    static var possibleValues:[String] { get }

    func getBla() -> Bla
}

class FooA : NSObject, FooProtocol {
    class var possibleValues:[String] {
        return [
            "Value A1",
            "Value A2",
            "Value A3"
        ]
    }

    func getBla() -> Bla {
        return Bla(withValues: FooA.possibleValues)
    }
}

class FooB : NSObject, FooProtocol {
    class var possibleValues:[String] {
        return [
            "Value B1",
            "Value B2",
            "Value B3",
            "Value B4"
        ]
    }

    func getBla() -> Bla {
        return Bla(withValues: FooB.possibleValues)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite. There are a few issues.  First, `FooA` and `FooB` don't implement `ObjCProtocolRequiringBla` which as shown is a requirement.  Also, they both seem to have to manually implement `getBla()` which should be handled by the base class.  Also, not sure how `FooContainer` fits into it as neither `FooA` nor `FooB` inherit from it.  Like @Matt said, it doesn't seem Swift supports the ability to make this a compile-time requirement specifically because of the Objective-C requirement.